# error login or password in authentication in flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, authorization

I have two forms:
auth.html

```
    <form class="form-signin pt-5" action="/auth/" method="post" >

        {% if error_msg: %}

{{ error_msg }}
```

{% endif %}

```
      <div class="mt-5 form-label-group">
        <p class="text-muted">email</p>

        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name = "email" required autofocus>

      </div>
      <div class="form-label-group">
        <p class="text-muted"> password</p>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name="password" class="form-control" required>
        <label for="inputPassword"></label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox mb-3"></div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Enter</button>
    </form>
```

success form.html

## Success

code in flask is:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "randomstring"
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret_key"
app.config["EMAIL"] = "test@test.ru"
app.config["PASSWORD"] = "test"

@app.route("/auth/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def auth_open():
    error_msg = ""  # Пока ошибок нет

    if request.method == "POST":

        email = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")

        if ((email and password) and email == app.config["EMAIL"] and password == app.config["PASSWORD"]):
            session["is_auth"] = True
            return render_template("/")

        else:
            error_msg = "Error login or password"

    return render_template("auth.html", error_msg=error_msg)
```

When I input password and login it shows me error message instead of success form.How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Your form has email field but you are trying to get username field

Comment: and how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

email = request.form.get("email")